# How can I set protected mode of internet options via cmd

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, cmd, internet-explorer-11, internet-options

How can I set protected mode of internet options via cmd?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question will give you some additional information on how to do this.

https://superuser.com/questions/1031225/what-is-the-registry-setting-to-enable-protected-mode-in-a-specific-zone

Use REG in your command line to change the value you are looking for.  The specific path of what you are looking for is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\2500
```

Read in the link for more specifics however I do believe this is what you are looking for.